# Reflections in lake vs swimming pool

Tags: optics, everyday-life, reflection

Why do lakes reflect objects better than swimming pools? Is it because light reflects from light but not dark bottoms, thereby obscuring reflection?

Comment: Wellcome to stack exchange.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/422844/only-sea-water-appears-blue-in-color-why-this-is-not-happening-in-river-water

Answer (score 1):

I think your suggestion is right. If you look out of the window in a train that drives into a tunnel, you suddenly see yourself in the window. This is not because the reflection coefficient of the window increased, but because all the light passing through the window from the outside is not there anymore. If the bottom is light (pool) you see that light stronger than the reflected light. But the reflection from the water-air interface is the same in both cases, assuming that both cases are pure water.

Comment: In principle I agree with you, however, your answer is still shaky. First of all, Ellens hypothesis is incorrect. As you stated yourself, the reflection coefficient does not change. Maybe you could also emphasise the concept of optical contrast a little bit more. E.g., although the stars at the sky do not vanish during the day, we are unable to see them.